# How can i get all functionality of jquery plugin after ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

I have using FormSliderSwitcher boostrap plugin in my web page and i have init that plugin on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    FormSliderSwitcher.init();
});
```

I have used this plugin all functionality on the page but after ajax call i dosent used this plugin functionality on newly append HTML after Ajax

if i would try to work with below code

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    FormSliderSwitcher.init();
});
```

then every time AJAX call multiple switches append in HTML again and again so please help me How can i get plugin functionality after ajax without init that plugin again ? or also would be better to give idea how to know plugin already initialize or not ?

Comment: where is the code that appends the new html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep a variable :). Simple enough.

```
vAjaxCompletedOnce=false;
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    if(vAjaxCompletedOnce==false){
      FormSliderSwitcher.init();
      vAjaxCompletedOnce =true;

    }
});
```

Comment: how will this work on numerous ajax calls when it needs to be initialized on new elements?

Comment: I don't have any idea of what FormSliderSwitcher.init() does. As OP asked how to do it once. My answer is so.